# yii2 show blank page in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, yii2

I used yii2 before in windows.but now I move a project to ubuntu but I get a blank page.I add to index.php this `code ini_set('display_errors', 1);` but my page is blank too.What reasons can be have?ofcourse I use .htaccess for pretty url

Comment: In your project folder  there have an php file requirements.php .open this file and check your server settings.

Comment: Check Your vendor `directory`

Comment: thanks for your help @jithin

Comment: Please check Apache error log in `var/log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check my requirements and add intl extension by

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

and activate mod_rewrite.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and 
 in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

change  `AllowOverride None` to  `AllowOverride All`

and then restart apache by

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check vendor folder in root is available or not.
2) Debug and find if any file is not getting included / getting fatal error in index.php file in below folder for frontend.
   http://localhost/foldername/frontend/web/index.php
3) If till not success go for vendor folder removal